# Are release files are enough for running a WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, release

In my WPF app under the project solution, I have some other class library projects.

The structure looks like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question: When I build my app under release, the app works great when I run the executable, but if I take only the release folder and move it to some other location, then the app doesn't start. Should it work with only the release folder?

Comment: it is [xcopy deployment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY_deployment) which normally works for WPF app

Comment: you should check your resource files' properties for **copy to output directory**

Comment: Compiled code relies on either The same Net Library being on the deployed PC or Publishing the Application.  The Net dlls have to be on the deployed PC and Publish will do the installing.

Comment: Check the event log for the error message. There can be different causes, for example, in you code use relative path to locate a dependency, when more to other location you get a filenotfoundexception.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the event viewer and where the exception was occurred, and that fixed the issue